# Why doesn't my PHP recognize my file? Isset

Tags: php

Hi I am new to PHP and I am trying to upload an image, Why doesn't my PHP recognize my file? my code will not pass the following line:

```
}else if(isset($_FILES['newspic'])) {
```

My Html is below

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
        Please complete your PAP below:<br />
      <textarea id="post" name="post" rows="4" cols="60"></textarea><br />
       Web Link: <input type="text" name="weblink" value="http:\\www."><br />
       Tag: <input type="text" name="tag"><br />
       Post Image: <input type="file" name="newspic"><br />

       <input type="submit" name="send" value="Post" />
      </form>
```

Comment: You forgot an enctype on the form as stated in the docs.

Comment: This is not a _complete_, minimal example. Any one of a million things could be wrong.

Comment: You forgot `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` tag, which means NO upload is being performed, and $_FILES will never get anythign set.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

So the full code is:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Please complete your PAP below:<br />
  <textarea id="post" name="post" rows="4" cols="60"></textarea><br />
   Web Link: <input type="text" name="weblink" value="http:\\www."><br />
   Tag: <input type="text" name="tag"><br />
   Post Image: <input type="file" name="newspic"><br />

   <input type="submit" name="send" value="Post" />
  </form>
```

Also use this:

```
}else if(isset($_POST['newspic'])) {
```

or

```
}else if(isset($_FILES["newspic"]["name"])) {
```

Comment: TY for your help Kevinkuijer

Comment: @Kevinkiujer is there a reason OP should check isset($_FILES["newspic"]["name"]) instead of just isset($_FILES["newspic"]) ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `enctype` to your form to allow sending files.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```